# Yellow and brown spots on leaf tip

Tags: leaves, diseases, food-crops, parasites, weather

On a barley farm, there are yellow and brown spots on leaf tips.

Possible causes:

- Some kind of parasite
- Weather condition
- Bad seed

  - Looks like some farms using the same seed are affected

What might be the actual cause? What could be the solution?

[image: leaf]

[image: leaf]

[image: leaf]

[image: leaf]

[image: leaf]